# How to synchronize Reactive Form value with underlined model in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a Reactive Form in Angular 8 containing a list of editable users (FormArray), based on a list of users. Is there a way to keep original users synchronized with the form value? 
The problem is that users are displayed in a table which uses original list as model. If these two are not synchronized, properties like filtering and sorting are messed up. 
Is any better way than watching for updates in every form control and update the model accordingly?

Comment: Yes there's a way, using ngx-sub-form would help :) check that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671796/designing-nested-reactive-forms-from-nested-classes/56732140#56732140

Answer (score 0):

There is a bad way for it but anyway i will say it for purpose of help.
When u pass the user data to the next page pass it with also a service that store the object of user u pressed on and  u could get the result u updated to the main list by splicing the index of the stored array in service with the main selected user and then u could put old or new data since i didn't get what u want exaclty.